# Why Main.storyboard doesn't show?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I'm new to ios develop,I learned about storyboard recently and I'm trying to use it.But at last the storyboard file looks doesn't be loaded.

What I have done is:

1.add some ui elements like Button to initial xib file of storyboard

2.modify **Main Interface** in project - General page to **Main**.(my storyboard file name is Main.storyboard)

When I start the app,the screen is all white with nothing.Anyone can tell me why this happened and how can I solve this bug.Thanks!

Update1:As this image shows,I have set initial xib for storyboard.

[image]

Comment: do u have any code in ur app delegate didFInish method ?

Comment: did u create the project with storyboard template ?

Comment: @Mr.T,  No,I havn't.It's necessary to do?

Comment: no, it is not necessary!!!! so u have any code in your app delegate related to window or setting root VC ?

Comment: No,except I mentioned above I didn't write any code.Because I learned the xcode will do these automatically from a site.

Comment: i have 2 views controller one as root, but the second page when i add some ui like buttons textfield, etc and run the app , i go back to the main storyboard i see the second page as blank . how can i see the sub views or the buttons , textfield...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Since you said you didn't created the project with a storyboard template, look for this line in your info.plist
   [image: info.plist]
2. This could happen because the subview frames are being created outside the view frame. Try setting some alignment constraints in your subviews.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks,it's exactly the second reason you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your controller as initial view controller.
You can find it in your Main.Storyboard on the right site, if you select your first controller.

[image]

Comment: Hope this answer helps, if you need further information, how to find the checkbox, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks,but I'm sure I have set initial controller for the storyboard.

Comment: I can see in your image the left controller.... maybe you have to set the left controller to inital view controller and not the current one?

Comment: I have updated my question with an image,I think I have done you said but the result is the same as before.

Comment: Just one ViewController,I have updated capture image.

Comment: you can open your main.storyboard file with right-click: open as -> source code. maybe there are false automatically generated code snippets...

Answer (score 0):

Here in 2021, a default Xcode project uses scenes, but that requires iOS 13 and I wanted to support iOS 12. I deleted the SceneDelegate file from my project and the scene delegate functions from the AppDelegate file, but then my storyboard wasn't loading either. The problem is that I also needed to remove the Application Scene Manifest section from info.plist.